# jQuery validation moves bootstrap button add-on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin and it works great - however, on a field where I am using a bootstrap button add-on, when the required alert is shown, the button doesn't move with the text box - I've replicated the issue here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhb5bb65/)

[image]

Here is the html:

```
<form id="frmPO" action="" method="get" runat="server">
<div class="form-group input-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="txtClientContract">
                        Client Contract</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtClientContract" runat="server" required/>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnClientContracts" >
                                ...</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                  </br>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <button id="btnSavePO" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                        Create Purchase Order</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: can you add some custom css or use only bootstrap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the label inserted by validation plugin between input and span.
You can add label for error message manually after div tag like this:-

```
 <label for="txtClientContract" generated="true" class="error"></label>
 //          ^ this is id for input
```

[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhb5bb65/1/)

Comment: @leddy happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it:

```
$(".input-group").find("label.error").detach().insertAfter($(".input-group"));
```

Adding the above line of code before `alert("not valid!");` solved your issue.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qhb5bb65/2/)

Basically what this does is it finds the error message and moves it after the button group so as not to break the structure using JQuery.