# Bootstrap textboxes alignment

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap, I have a field in Model with multiple validations, 
(Bootstrap v3.1.1 With Asp.net MVC 4)

**Model Validations Are:**

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Mobile number.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers (0-9) Are Allowed.")]
    [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "10 Characters only.")]
     public string mobileNumber { get; set; }
```

**View Code Is:**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="dvID">
            <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Heading Here</strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Mobile Number<span class="reruiredField"> * </span></label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.mobileNumber, new { id = "txtdistrictCode", maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control", title = "" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.mobileNumber)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
```

**Generated HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Cluster Code<span class="reruiredField"> * </span></label>
    <input type="text" value="" title="" placeholder="Cluster Code" name="ClusterCode" maxlength="9" id="txtClusterCode" data-val-required="Please Enter Cluster Code" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]+$" data-val-regex="Only Numbers (0-9) Are Allowed." data-val-length-max="9" data-val-length="9 Characters allowed." data-val="true" class="form-control">
   <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ClusterCode" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
                    </div>
```

When I First Submit Button Validation Fires Properly, No problem there

[image]

When I don't click Submit button, just types characters in text box (mobileNumber), validation message ""Only Numbers (0-9) Are Allowed." is shown (  Which is also Correct)

But here in Later case the text box below is shifted towards right side as shown in screen shot:

[image]

When I click Submit button It again gets to its proper position

How can I Fix That text box positions for multiple validation messages?

Comment: Could this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200856/jquery-validation-moves-bootstrap-button-add-on (suggest adding a label for the error msg)

Comment: It MVC creates a span tag for validations below text box, I can post generated `html` in qus if you need ?

Comment: @jtheman, I have posted Html generated...

Comment: Use browser debugger  to find out which css bit causing that issue.

Comment: @CodeDecode , class `field-validation-valid` on span  is defined in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` OR `jquery.validate.min.js`

Comment: field-validation-valid defined in default MVC project .check your project default css.